# Getting value from series click event, and display on legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

What I wanted to do was to get the price from the click event, (which is the y value in this case) and be able to use it as a variable to display on the name dynamically when clicking on different set of data. The code below is what I wrote and obviously didn't work. What can I do here? Need Help~

```
plotOptions: {
                    line: {

                    },
                    series: {
                          cursor: 'pointer',
                          point: {
                                events: {
                                      click: function (events) {
                                            var price = events.y;
                                      }
                                }
                          }
                    }
              },
              series: [{
                          name:'bank sold at price : ' + price,

                          data: [
                                [Date.UTC(2017, 5, 1), 29.74],
                                [Date.UTC(2017, 5, 2), 29.745],
                                [Date.UTC(2017, 5, 3), 29.735],
                                [Date.UTC(2017, 5, 5), 29.73],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `plotOptions`

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      cursor: "pointer",
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function(events) {                    
            var chart = this.series.chart; //define charts 
            price = this.y;
            chart.series[0].update({ name: "bank sold at price :" + price }, false); //update chart series name
            chart.redraw(); //redraw charts

          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GdMWrR)

Comment: Hi is it okay if i ask you something extra, how do I add a Date on legend label, so when I clicked on the chart it also displays the date (x value), cuz when I called this.x it turns to some weird meaningless number. I would like it with date formate thanks~

Comment: dudeeee @Deep3015~ call out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343437/highcharts-to-rotate-the-chart-90-degree-but-also-redraw-it